# Installing Craft 3 on Cpanel

Tags: craft3, control-panel, hosting

Can I install Craft 3 using cPanel instead of composer. Any suggestion or guide on it? I tried find tutorials but found for Craft 2, not for Craft 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Mijingo resource that should help: https://mijingo.com/blog/manually-installing-craft-3

Answer (score 1):

This is a detailed tutorial for installing craft into cpanel: https://www.geniusesforhire.com/blog/install-craft-cms-in-cpanel